# Ionic/Android pixelated icons

Tags: android, ionic-framework, resolution

So I have some icons in my Ionic app, mostly 512x512 px. I've tried the app on iOS and everything looks good, but when I run it on Android device all the icons look pixelated. I'm using a 1200x800 Android tablet so could this the issue or there is something else ?

Comment: Let us know how is your XML and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: screenshots can also help here

Answer (score 0):

you can use android and iOS icons from http://ionicons.com